# SQL update in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

my problem is: I need to select all my db-tables which contain a column NrPad out of my database and for exactly this tables I need to update the column NrPad

I have already a working select and update statement:

```
select
    t.name as table_name
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c
on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.name like 'NrPad'

Update Anlage Set NrPad = CASE WHEN Len(Nr) < 10 THEN '0' + Convert(Nvarchar,Len(Nr)) ELSE Convert(Nvarchar,Len(Nr)) END + Nr
```

My problem is: How can I merge this two statements together?

I'm open to suggestions and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't say what dbms you are using, In case its oracle than the answer is in your question, you have MERGE statement which updates a table by another table or select in your case

Comment: Update `NrPad` in all tables to add another `0`? You need a cursor and create the UPDATE using dynamic SQL.

Comment: like dnoeth said cursor is like the only solution, oracle merge statement is just update by another table not update multiple tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` rather than `sys.tables`, and create a dynamic SQL statement like so:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = '';

SELECT
    @sql = @sql + '; UPDATE ' + c.TABLE_NAME + ' SET NrPAd = CASE WHEN LEN(Nr)<10 THEN ''0'' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,LEN(NR)) ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,LEN(NR)) END + Nr'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where c.COLUMN_NAME = 'NrPad'


print @sql -- for debugging purposes
exec (@sql)
```

This assumes that all tables that have the `NrPad` column also have a `Nr` column.  If you need to check for those, or if you just need to use the `Nr` column from a particular table, it's a bit different (either join against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` again or against `Anglage` to get the value of Nr or check that Nr is a column on that table).

Comment: No prob - if you found it helpful, consider marking it as the accepted answer (the check under the vote rocker).

Answer (score 0):

Not testet on your case but you could do an update - set - from - where.

Have a look at this question with multiple answers: [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone will judge me,but all i can do for this case is cursor

```
    DECLARE @table_name varchar(100)
    DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
    DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
     select
       t.name as table_name
     from sys.tables t
     inner join sys.columns c
             on t.object_id = c.object_id
          where c.name like 'NrPad'
   OPEN table_cursor
   Fetch next From table_cursor Into @table_name
    While @@fetch_status=0     
   Begin
     set @sql = 'Update' + @table_name + 'Set NrPad = CASE WHEN Len(Nr) < 10 THEN '0' + Convert(Nvarchar,Len(Nr)) 
                        ELSE Convert(Nvarchar,Len(Nr)) END + Nr'
     EXEC (@sql)
   Fetch Next From table_cursor Into @table_name
   End   
   Close table_cursor   
   Deallocate table_cursor
```

this is how you write the cursor in SQLSERVER, i really don't want code another one for Oracle. so please tag the dbms you are using next time

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about the dbms I'm using - it's Microsoft SQLServer 2014. Thank you for your solution with the cursor. The only problem is, that I cannot use table names as variables (right?). I tried your solution and the only problem is that @table_name after UPDATE "Must declare the table variable "@table_name".

Comment: oh,it's my bad not using dynamic SQL,i edited the answer and tested it,it will be fine. you could try it again @user1474960

Comment: @user1474960 glad that help if you could please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the select statement to generate the update statements then execute them all.

Below uses string literal of Oracle.

```
select 'Update ' || t.name || q'[ Set NrPad = CASE WHEN Len(Nr) < 10 THEN '0' + Convert(Nvarchar,Len(Nr)) ELSE Convert(Nvarchar,Len(Nr)) END + Nr;]'
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c
on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.name like 'NrPad'
```